# C# Command Line Building

Tags: c#, command-line, building

the book I'm reading went briefly over command line building, specifically controlling the linker.

But any class and .cs file containing classes or resources seems to link just fine if they reside inside my project, can I just ignore the command line builder for now until I'm more profficient in C# or is this something I need to know right now?

Comment: Are you referring to compiling a C# project using the Visual Studio Command Line?

Comment: I would say for learning you can go through the excercise, but dont pull your hair on it and save them for real problems :)

Answer (score 1):

CommandLine builder using csc.exe in my knowledge is not used by even experienced professionals. Everyone goes the route of Visual Studio latest versions and it is safe to ignore commandline building.

But you can try and understand how it works. Because, in the end this is the one which is used  by your GUI tools like Visual Studio to do the build.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally say it is worth knowing how to use the command line building, but it is not a necessity. I started off just using Visual Studio and wasn't even aware of command line building for C#. However, since I learned to use it and write Command Script files to execute it, I actually use it fairly often - especially when working on large projects that have multiple dependencies in need of building. In that situation, it saves opening multiple Visual Studio instances.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Muthu. Building via CSC.exe is good option and works for simple setups or for learning, but if you have a complex solution structure in Visual Studio using inter-project dependencies, post build events, etc. its best to just invoke the Visual Studio build call itself via the command line. The command is devenv.exe and you'll find lots of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on it.

If you are trying to learn C# complier/linker innards maybe you'll be more interested in [Project Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) from Microsoft as they try to open the "black box" of the compiler.